# Got "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" when including a simple Component JS file in my HTML file (without Node.js)

Tags: reactjs

What I want to do is actually really simple, BUT I want do to it without using Node.js.

Juste a simple HTML file with a Component in a separate .js file.

Here is the HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>React Local</title>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>

  <script type="text/babel" data-type="module"  src="./TestComponent.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/babel">

        // Obtain the root 
        const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
    
        ReactDOM.render(
          <TestComponent />,
          rootElement
        )

    </script>
  
    <div id="root"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

You can see that I import my component file with type="text/babel" data-type="module"

Here is the TestComponent.js file :

```
// Create a ES6 class component    
class TestComponent extends React.Component { 
    render() { 
        return (
        <span>HELLO</span>
      );
      } 
    }

export default TestComponent;
```

But the .js file is not loaded, and in the Chrome console I see :

```
VM99:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at <anonymous>:3:23
    at run (babel.js:61531:11)
    at check (babel.js:61597:10)
    at result.<computed>._extends.content (babel.js:61624:10)
    at xhr.onreadystatechange (babel.js:61549:10)
```

I did not except that almost all React tutorials are related with Node.js.
I have a PHP application, and I only need React for small simple stuff, don't want to add nodeJS just for that.

Any clue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out. Just remove the line : export default TestComponent;
No need to "export" the component in that case.